# libdb not found on raspberry pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I am trying to set up emerald crypto mining software on my raspberry pi. I am using the ARM distribution of the wallet for raspberry pi, available here: https://www.emeraldcrypto.de

I can compile the wallet fine, but when I run it with ./emeraldd, I get the error "error while loading shared libraries: libdb_cxx-5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

I tried to fix this with a general apt-get update and upgrade, then by apt-get install libdb5.3++. It said that libdb5.3 was already on the machine and fully updated. What can I do instead to fix it?

Thank you

EDIT: sudo apt-get install libdb5.3++-dev doesn't work either, it says there is no package by that name.

Comment: It would be super helpful if you included the operating system and version you're using.

Comment: @ghoti standard raspberry pi pixel/raspbian os

Comment: I'm suggesting that you include this sort of thing in your question, rather than comments. For ME, for example, my "standard" operating system on Raspberry Pis is FreeBSD version 11.0, as I haven't yet upgraded my Pis to 11.1. The Pi is a *platform*. Don't assume there's only one way to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea but you got one thing wrong. When you compile a program you need to have the -dev version of the dependency installed.
So try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libdb5.3++-dev
```

It should install the necessary files to compile a program that uses libdb.

Comment: I tried that, it tells me that it is unable to locate a package with that name.

Comment: I searched through the package list try installing libdb5.3-dev instead

Comment: thanks for looking, but that didn't work either. I tried a bunch of variations that also didn't work. I'm trying to install from my Downloads folder, is there someplace else where it could find the package?

Comment: You can try https://pkgs.org/download/libdb5.3++-dev or https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libdb5.3++-dev for a .deb.